# call twirl template from ScalaJs

Tags: sbt, playback, scala.js, twirl

The play framework documentation says (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaTemplates):  You can then call this from any Scala code as you would normally call a method on a class:

```
val content = views.html.Application.index(c, o)
```

Is there an easy way to call twirl templates within ScalaJs for a
crossProject(JSPlatform, JVMPlatform).crossType(CrossType.Pure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that Twirl, the templating framework of Play, supports Scala.js, it should relatively simple. The only thing is that, by default, Twirl will not look for templates in the shared source directory. So you'll need to configure its source directories, as explained [in its readme](https://github.com/playframework/twirl#source-directories), using something like:

```scala
sourceDirectories in (Compile, TwirlKeys.compileTemplates) +=
  baseDirectory.value.getParentFile / "src/main/twirl"
```

Comment: Wonder if its not easier to do this on demand on the server side, e.g.:
   
      Ajax.get("/view/application/footer").map(_.responseText).map { 
        content => $("#view_application_footer").replaceWith(content) 
      }

and get rid of all the marshalling/unmarshalling (json.decode/encode), 
keeping object model on server side ... (but PWA?)